# Would slowing down a beam of light change its wavelength and frequency?

Tags: visible-light, speed-of-light, frequency, wavelength

I confess that I have little knowledge of physics, so this kind of thing really often goes over my head. However, I did read somewhere that the speed of a beam of light is the product of its wavelength multiplied by its frequency. If that's true, if I were to lower the speed, would that not mean its wavelength and/or frequency would be lower as well?

Comment: If you are talking about light propagating in vacuum then there is no way to slow it down.

Comment: And when the light goes from vacuum to glass, the speed changes, but the frequency remains the same. Hence the wavelength is different in the glass.